# How to add a RTF input box using adaptive card?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am creating a Teams bot. I want to enable user to provide input using adaptive card input box. How should I configure the adaptive card so it can enable the user to format the text they sent. I want to add RTF enabled editor.

Current state:
I have added Adaptive Card with below columnset

```cs
new AdaptiveColumn()
{
    Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
        {
            new AdaptiveTextInput()
                {
                    Id="body",
                    Placeholder="Please type your message here",
                    IsMultiline=true,
                    Value=""
                }
         },
         Width="100"
}
```

Behavior: I get a input box to type in my message without any formatting option.

Expected: I want to add a box which allows me to add a message and format it as per my need. Currently it supports few markups to format the text, but I'm looking for a rich text editor.

Comment: Please add more information on your current progress and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @DaniVijay updated the question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

RTF is not available in Adaptive Card. Please have a look at [schema docs for all available Input field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/card-schema#schema-input.text).

You can use [Adaptive Card designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) to create your card UI which lets you drag and drop controls which are supported by Adaptive Card schema.

Comment: Is there any other way (other than adaptive card) to add a RTF input box in Teams bot?

Comment: You could invoke [Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview#what-a-task-module-looks-like) which lets you open HTML page with input fields.